# Combinatorial proof of a Fibonacci identity: $n F_1 + (n-1)F_2 + \cdots + F_n = F_{n+4} - n - 3.$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, fibonacci-numbers, combinatorial-proofs

Does anyone know a combinatorial proof of the following identity, where $F_n$ is the $n$th Fibonacci number?

$$n F_1 + (n-1)F_2 + \cdots + F_n = F_{n+4} - n - 3$$

It's not in the place I thought it most likely to appear: Benjamin and Quinn's *[Proofs That Really Count](http://books.google.com/books?id=FXLGzXwbwIAC&printsec=frontcover&dq=proofs+that+really+count&source=bl&ots=cLasNhVboM&sig=cgpcvX12VJy4hzDjlM8buMY1O1w&hl=en&ei=1RUVTY2vAY7EsAPklv3GAg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q&f=false)*.  In fact, this may be a hard problem, as they say the similar identity

$$ F_1 + 2F_2 + \cdots + nF_n = (n+1)F_{n+2} - F_{n+4} +2$$

is "in need of a combinatorial proof."

For reference, [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=n8Xx2oSlz4MC&pg=PA14&lpg=PA14&dq=benjamin+and+quinn+uncounted+fibonacci&source=bl&ots=UDfzehytLs&sig=mcWgV3BP2_Jyl5zi1fhL2EHqqfU&hl=en&ei=ThIVTcmsLo7ksQPcvMXIAg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q&f=false) (from Benjamin and Quinn's text) are several combinatorial interpretations of the Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: I know that You are looking for combinatorical proof, but it is easy to show that this is true using induction.

Comment: @Tomek: Yes, and I have another (non-inductive) proof that is also not combinatorial.  Right now I really am only interested in a combinatorial one - for aesthetic reasons. :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Recall that $F_{n+1}$ is the number of ways to tile a board of length $n$ with tiles of length $1$ and $2$.  So $F_{n+4}$ is the number of ways to tile a board of length $n+3$ with tiles of length $1$ and $2$.  Note that $n+3$ such tilings use at most one tile of length $2$, so $F_{n+4} - (n+3)$ such tilings use at least two tiles of length $2$.

Given such a tiling, look at where the second-to-last tile of length $2$ is used.  The part after this tile is a tiling of some section of length $k+1$ where exactly one tile of length $2$ is used (which can be done in $k$ ways), and the part before this tile is a tiling of the remaining portion of length $n-k$ (which can be done in $F_{n-k+1}$ ways).  Sum over $k$.

(The bigger lesson to take away here is that convolution is much easier to deal with than Hadamard product.  Also, since the bijection I described above preserves the number of tiles of each type, the identity can be upgraded to an identity of $q$-Fibonacci numbers.)

Comment: The other lesson to take away is that you can sometimes convert generating function identities directly into combinatorial proofs (which I imagine was your second proof); I think Zeilberger and others have written papers about the possibility of doing this automatically.

Comment: Beautiful!  And I second your comment about convolution generally being easier to deal with.