# Remarkable relation between Fibonacci numbers and its squares!

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

There is a remarkable relation between Fibonacci numbers and its squares:

> $F^{2}_{n} +F^{2}_{n+1}=F_{2n+1}$.

I know how to prove it using $F_{n}=\frac{\sqrt{5}}{5}((\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^n -(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})^n)$ formula, but I want a proof without this. By proof I don't mean a rigid one. I tried to use area of rectangles but no success! Also, I saw some proof by induction but it is not my point - I want a proof using picture and not rigid, that I hope I could explain well!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The identity from the question can be viewed in a completely different way.

First, Fibonacci number of order n can be defined as number of ways for 2×1 dominoes to cover a 2×n checkerboard:

n=3:

[image]

n=4:

[image]

n=5:

[image]

Then, one can use methods presented in [this paper](http://www.m-hikari.com/imf-2010/17-20-2010/krzywkowskiIMF17-20-2010.pdf) to prove the original identity.

---

There is another MSE question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15469/combinatorial-proof-of-a-fibonacci-identity-n-f-1-n-1f-2-cdots-f-n), that makes use of tiling, but with different tiles, and proves identity:

$$n F_1 + (n-1)F_2 + \cdots + F_n = F_{n+4} - n - 3$$

Answer (score 3):

This relation is particular case  of **Catalan's Identity**:
$$ F_n^2 - F_{n+r}F_{n-r} = (-1)^{n-r}F_r^2 $$
With $r = n+1 $  we have
$$ F_n^2 - F_{2n+1}F_{1} = (-1)^{2n-1}F_{n+1}^2  \Rightarrow F_n^2 + F_{n+1}^2 = F_{2n+1} $$

(Refer to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) )