# Fibonacci Numbers Identity ${F_n}^2 + {F_{n+1}}^2 = F_{2n+1}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, fibonacci-numbers

Prove the following identities involving Fibonacci numbers:
$${F_n}^2 + {F_{n+1}}^2 = F_{2n+1}.$$
I am not sure how to work with the 2n's.

Comment: Can you use [Binet's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression)?

Comment: It is answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/300345/induction-proof-fibonacci-numbers-identity-with-sum-of-two-squares).

Comment: Also see a nice visual explanation [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/936383/remarkable-relation-between-fibonacci-numbers-and-its-squares/936594#936594)

Comment: You can use the matrix form or induction to prove it, or even use Binet's formula directly.